# Highcharts javascript library - marker halo zIndex?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to have the halo around the marker to be white and appear above the plot line but I can't see any way to do it. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e1r9g59q/)

I made the halo gray to demonstrate that it appears under the plot line.

```
hover: {
  halo: {
    attributes: {
      stroke: 'white'
    },
    opacity: 1,
    size: 10
  },
  fillColor: '#fff',
  lineColor: null,
  lineWidth: 2,
  radius: 3
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap render function, set zIndex for marker higher than series. Last step is apply zIndex for halo, by attributes.

```
halo: {
                        opacity: 0.75,
                        size: 10,
                        attributes: {
                            zIndex: 4,
                            fill: 'gray',
                                'stroke-width': 0,
                            stroke: ''
                        }
                    }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e1r9g59q/2/